# DataAdapter не сохраняет данные в БД

Tags: c#

В программе напрямую присваиваю значение датасету, пытаясь изменить данные в БД

```
for (int j=1; j< dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray.Count; j++)
{
   dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[j] = matrixAlternativ[0][j];
   dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[j] = matrixAlternativ[1][j];
   dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[2].ItemArray[j] = matrixAlternativ[2][j];
}
```

После этого хочу эти изменения сохранить

```
connection.open();
dataSetPlayerSkill.AcceptChanges();
adapter.Update(dataSetPlayerSkill);
connection.Close();
```

Но они не сохраняются.
Моя БД состоит из [Код] - счетчик(первичный ключ), [Поле1] - текст

Если убрать `dataSetPlayerSkill.AcceptChanges();` то возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, а что этот вопрос идентифицирует как [tag:ado.net] ?

Comment: @4per `DataSet`, `DataAdapter`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov так это общие классы, не для ado.net именно

Answer (score 2):

Просто уберите `dataSetPlayerSkill.AcceptChanges();` Данный метод изменяет признак у изменённых строк, устанавливая *"неизменённый"*. Метод, полезен в других случаях, но не когда вы желаете сохранить изменения в базу данных.

---

Ошибка, которую вы демонстрируете в обновлении вопроса, свидетельствует о том, что ответ вам помог, и ваш `adapter` начал вызывать команду, которая хранится в его свойстве `UpdateCommand`. Но он столкнулся с проблемой при вызове этой команды. Возможно, команда не задана или задана неправильная команда.

Comment: Убрал, появилась ошибка про UpdateCommand

Comment: это потому что, до этого `adapter.UpdateCommand` не работал. Разбирайтесь, что с ним не так. Что именно из вашего примера однозначно сказать нельзя, и является проблемой другого рода, чем вы изначально обозначили в вопросе. Вы получили ответ на вопрос.